# How to sketch commutative property of convolution

Tags: convolution

I've been asked to sketch why

$$y(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x(k)h(n-k) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}h(k)x(n-k)$$

are equivalent expressions for convolution. I could explain this pretty easily with a proof, but can't think of a concise way to illustrate this. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If you can prove it, what is left to illustrate? Are you looking for confirmation on the proof? Show it!

Comment: I'm not looking for confirmation of the proof. Just would like to show a graphical representation. Not for any reason other than being asked by my professor. Would convolving say x(n) = [1 1 2  0 0] with the impulse response be an ok example to use?

Comment: I have no idea what that means. Do you know the relationship of convolution with multiplication of power series?